# Why magento configurable product have no "Add to cart" button?

Tags: magento

I am working on magento project. Its my first magento project. But i have learned a lot.
I have applied theme to simple products details successfully in

```
template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

Now i want to change theme for configurable products. Where can i find code for configurable products on front end? Add to cart button is not showing in configurable products.

Answer (score 2):

Magento's configurable product is actually wrapper over it's simple children. The 'add to cart' button adds simple product based on selected attributes. So, if there is no simple children available, the button 'add to cart' will not show up.
If you want to change theme files for configurable products you should look into the `PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable` layout handle or use `$product->isConfigurable()` in templates.

Comment: Where is the phtml for configurable products detail?

Comment: there is no special phtml for configurable products. instead of having separate page template for each product type magento has one general template for all products and type-related blocks are injected via layout handle (such as PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable). check the catalog.xml layout file and catalog/product.phtml template.